# I don't want to provide defaultValue to AutoComplete component. But, getting the warning : MUI AutoComplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [this AutoComplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) component from MUI. But, I don't want to provide default value because I don't want any options to be selected initially. I want the value to be empty until user selects. But, I am getting this warning :

```
useControlled.js:19 MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Autocomplete to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Autocomplete element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not `undefined`.
```

It makes sense, if we don't provide defaultValue, it's undefined and later on when we change it to string, this gives us this warning. I also tried providing `empty string ''` as `defaultValue`, but that also gives another warning

```
useAutocomplete.js:220 MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
None of the options match with `""`.
You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.
```

**How can I fix this??**

Comment: From their code sample, I think you can use `null` as the default value. `inputValue` can be `empty string` but `value` is an option.
If you allow anything to be written there, `freeSolo` might be the prop you can use alternatively.

Comment: Please provide the code sample of how you are using this component